# Remove a row from database to create a new list

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am able to see that my database is saving correctly when I first create it after looping through my parsed xml web service response. The issue is, I am trying to remove a row from within that table and there are two rows with the same employeeNumber. I have a method that I am trying to delete one of the records so I can use the other to make the new List to populate a listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mTopList, directReportListView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    private BottomListViewAdapter mBottomListViewAdapter;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    private String startingEmployeeID = employeeNumberWishToDelete;
    private String table = "employees";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());

        directReportListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBottomListViewAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mEmployees);
        directReportListView.setAdapter(mBottomListViewAdapter);
        getBottomViewXMLData();

        displayTopList(startingEmployeeID);

        //displayTopList();


        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);


    }

    public void getBottomViewXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }

                mEmployees.clear();
                mEmployees.addAll(employees);

                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList(String employeeNumber) {
        String table = "employees";
        String whereClause = "Employee_number=?";
        String[] whereArgs  = new String[] {String.valueOf(employeeNumber)};
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
      //  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) dbHandler.getEmployee(startingEmployeeID);
     //   Log.i("ADAM", cursor.toString());
    }
}
```

When I run it, I am getting

Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
                  Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
                    (UNIQUE constraint failed: employees.Employee_number (code 1555)).

I know its because the second record with the same employeeNumber isn't being deleted. Not sure why the above code isn't deleting the record. Is it possible to delete 1 row and use it in another list?

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employees";

    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";


    public EmployeeDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);

        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


        //Inserting Row
        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Employee employee = null;

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] {
                KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                employee = new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                        cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                        cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                        cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                        cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
            }
        }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
            return employee;

    }

    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }

    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());

        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried several things with cursors and simpleadapters but nothing I do seems to delete the records and populate another listview." This is the correct way to do it. You should show exactly what you tried.

Comment: I have updated my code with the method that I am using to try and delete a duplicate record

Comment: Remember that Java code must have a class. Please show this in the code posted here.

Comment: What's the complete database schema?

Comment: Also, you should use CursorAdapter rather than ArrayAdapter when connecting a ListView with a database.

Comment: How are there two rows with the same employee number when the employee number is the primary key?

Comment: I have made the primary key the employee id, there are 2 records for only 1 person with the web service and that's because they have created 2.  I am unable to get them to delete one of them. I have updated my code with the whole class that contains that method.

Comment: I'm mostly confused how the two records with the same primary key were even allowed in the first place.

Comment: I am not sure, I am able to pull the database up with Stetho and see that there is only 1 record in there with that employee number but the response actually has the same person twice. So I would assume that for some reason Stetho isn't showing the record twice but it is still there.

Comment: The SQLite insert will fail for a duplicate primary key, so, this is a non-issue. You shouldn't assume Stetho doesn't show a record

Comment: Then why is the BottomListView populated with the data if it should save 2 records? Should I try to remove that second employeeNumber entry when looping through the ArrayList in the onResponse?

Answer (score 1):

Are there other records with a duplicate Employee_number?  Those will also cause the issue you are reporting.  You've violated the constraint that there can't be multiple records with the same Employee_number.  If you need to have multiple records with the same Employee_number, set another primary key (auto increment perhaps) instead.  Then your delete command will delete both records.

Edit: You can't violate the constraint you've created, so you need to either ensure you don't violate it when you add records (check for a pre-existing Employee_number before you add) or change your primary key as suggested.

Edit 2:
Here is the syntax for a table with an automatic primary key:
Adding to this table will automatically populate 'id' for you, ensuring it is unique.

```
 String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_ID + " STRING,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT, "
                ...
```

Comment: No there is only 1 duplicate record in the web service and I am unable to get them to remove that duplicate so I am trying to do it in SQLite after I have parsed and stored the response.

Comment: Is it possible to create a unique ID that isn't tied to the response or POJO? Just creates a 1, 2, 3, etc for each row that is added? Maybe that way I can get that specific new unique id and delete that? Thought about using something like Sugar ORM but that wouldn't help as I have the same employeeNumber being added twice to the database.

Comment: Yes, that is the auto_increment column I was referring to - see edit 2 for an example